# How to select two columns which one of them having condition when join two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

Table #1: **allusers**

- userid
- department
- status(0 or 1)
- is_online

Table #2: **userlog**

- userlogid
- logintime

I want to join two tables like this:

(group by department)

- department
- count(*)==>allusers
- count(*)==> status= 1
- count(*) ==> table1.userid=table2.userlogid

I dont know how to show the column about count(*)==> status= 1

I cant group the column of 'count(*)==> status= 1 '

Please help me check my codes

```
select o.department as DM,
       count(p.userlogid) as userlog,
       count(o.department) as alluser,
       count(p.userlogid)  as userlog1
from table2 as p
right OUTER join table1 as o
on p.userlogid=o.USERID
on q.userlogid=o.userid
where o.status=1
group by o.department;
```

Comment: Sample data, expected results, and your attempt(s) will greatly help us help you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation.  But I would recommend that you use `left join` rather than `right join`.

Then, I think you want `count(distinct)`, to count users rather than log records::

```
select u.department as DM,
       count(distinct u.userid) as num_users,
       count(distinct l.userlogid) as num_log_users,
       count(distinct case when o.status = 1 then l.userlogid end) as num_status1_users
from allusers u left join
     userlog l
     on l.userlogid = u.USERID
group by o.department;
```

It is possible that you want to count the log records and not users.  If so, you can remove the `distinct`:

```
select u.department as DM,
       count(u.userid) as num_users,
       count(l.userlogid) as num_log_users,
       count(case when o.status = 1 then l.userlogid end) as num_status1_users
from allusers u left join
     userlog l
     on l.userlogid = u.USERID
group by o.department;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this query:

```
select o.department as DM,
       sum(1) allusers,
       sum(case when status=1 then 1 else 0 end) usersWithStatus1,
from table2 as p
right OUTER join table1 as o
on p.userlogid=o.USERID
GROUP BY o.department;
```

You case use `SUM` with `CASE` in order to perform some conditions.